# Why is the $\liminf$ of a stochastic process measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\{X(t)\}_{t \in \mathcal{T}}$ be a real valued stochastic process.

Why is the following function then measurable: $$\liminf_{s \downarrow t} X(s):= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\; (\inf\{X(s)| s \in \mathcal{T} \cap (t,t+\epsilon)\})?$$

(We have the infimum over more then countable many measurable functions here)

Comment: To prove that a real valued function $f$ is measurable it suffices to show that each $\{f\leq t\}$ is a measurable set. Try proving that if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of measurable functions then $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} f_n$ is measurable.

Comment: @fKonrad   Yes, but as I already mentioned, here we are not considering the infimum over countable many measurable functions